# custom underline goes over whole width (css)

Tags: jquery, css

I want a custom underline, the color will be different from time to time so i set it with jQuery.

```
$(".headline h1").css({
"text-decoration":"none",
"border-bottom":"2px solid #00ff0c", 
"padding":"0px"});
```

It only gives a underline as big as the paragraph, i only want the underline to be under the text itself. How can i do that?

```
<h1 style="text-decoration: none; border-bottom-width: 2px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 255, 12); padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; ">Noord-Korea is niet van plan van koers te veranderen</h1>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following into your stylesheet:

```
h1 { display: inline-block; }
```

This will make the width of `h1` only as wide as needed for its contents, as opposite to the default 100% width. But note this this also removes the default top and bottom margin of the element, so you may wish to set `margin-top' on the next element.

Comment: Thanks, this method is the fastest and look cleanest :)

Comment: @clankill3r: +1 to Jukka, but note that this means any content following it will be on the same visual line unless that content forces a linebreak itself (so for instance, `h1` followed by `p` will be fine, but not `h1` just followed by text).

Answer (score 4):

You can put a `span` in the `h1` that includes the text, then put the bottom border on that instead of on the `h1`. E.g.:

```
<h1><span style="text-decoration: none; border-bottom-width: 2px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 255, 12); padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; ">Noord-Korea is niet van plan van koers te veranderen</span></h1>
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/umozen)

(Side note: I'd recommend moving the style data to a stylesheet rather than using a massive inline `style` attribute. But that's (ugh) a matter of style.)

Comment: Is it possible to change a color from a stylesheet with javascript?

Comment: @clankill3r: It's possible, but it's ugly and there are some differences between browsers. Sorry, forgot you wanted to change it later. In that case, I think I'd put everything except the color in a style and apply the color to the element directly.

Answer (score 1):

Give your text an inline element that wraps it like this...

```
<h1 style="text-decoration: none; border-bottom-width: 2px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 255, 12); padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; "><span>Noord-Korea is niet van plan van koers te veranderen</span></h1>
```

Then apply your style to that inline element.

```
$(".headline h1 span").css({  "text-decoration":"none",  "border-bottom":"2px solid #00ff0c",   "padding":"0px"});
```

The reason for this is that h1 is a block-level element so it spans the entire width (like a paragraph); where as, span wraps just the word because it is an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the border-bottom stuff and using text-decoration underline does solve your problem?

```
text-decoration: underline;


$(".headline h1").css({"text-decoration":"underline"});
```